# Angular Material List Option returns true, even if false

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, logic

```
<mat-selection-list>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of permissionCategories()">
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <div mat-subheader>{{ cat }}</div>
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let permission of permissionsOfCategory(cat)"
            [selected]="havePermission(permission)"
        >
            {{ permission.Name }}
        </mat-list-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And

```
havePermission(permission: Permission): boolean {
    return this.currentRankPermissions.includes(permission.Id);
}
```

I checked houndred times all values, and they are correct
There are some permissions and `havePermission` **returns** true or false

> UseLspdTablet **true** 
> ModifyRanks **true** 
> AccessCitizenIndex **true** 
> AccessCitizenRegistry **false** 
> ArrestMandateCitizen **false** 
> ChangeCitizenPhoneNumber **false** 
> ModifyCitizenWanted **false** 
> ShowCitizenCrimeCount **false** 
> AccessVehicleIndex **false** 
> SetVehicleAsStolen **false** 
> SetVehicleAsWanted **false** 
> SetVehicleAsFound **false** 
> SetVehicleNote **false**

And every time I run this page, everything works perfectly, but then I wait 3 seconds (after this time there are some other updates on same page, **none of them are accessing any of this variables or something**) and then in console they still show ok, but in page they all are selected, **WHY**

Also I noticed that there are thousends of console logs of this = thousends of rerenders.

Rest of maybe important code:

```
  onTablesChanged() {
    this.allRanks = Array.from(this.db.Tables.Rank.values());

    if (this.permissionsOfRank.length <= 0) {
      this.permissionsOfRank = Array.from(this.db.Tables.PermissionOfRank.values());
    }
  }

  permissionCategories(): string[] {
    const res = [];
    Array.from(this.db.Tables.Permission.values()).forEach((permission: Permission) => {
      if (!res.includes(permission.Category)) {
        res.push(permission.Category);
      }
    });

    return res;
  }

  permissionsOfCategory(cat: string): Permission[] {
    return Array.from(this.db.Tables.Permission.values())
      .filter(c => c.Category === cat);
  }
```

Every 3 seconds `onTablesChanged` is called which cause this rerender, but it should cause 13 calls of `havePermission`, but it cause 99999999 of them, **WHY**

Windows 10
Angular 8.3.26
Typescript 3.5.3
@angular/material 8.2.3

I ran this on FiveM Application (GTA V) - which just use chromium.

**WHY**

Comment: How are where are you calling `onTablesChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general use a function in the .html is bad idea. I suppose your permissionCategories and permissionsOfCategory changes when the tables changes, that's you can mannage in the onTablesChanged. So you can use this function to calculate a variable `data` that was an array of object. Each object has two properties: `category` and `permissions` (this last is an array). So:

```
data:any[] //<--declare a variable
onTablesChanged() {
    this.allRanks = Array.from(this.db.Tables.Rank.values());

    if (this.permissionsOfRank.length <= 0) {
      this.permissionsOfRank = Array.from(this.db.Tables.PermissionOfRank.values());
    }
    //here calculate data in the way
    data=this.permissionCategories().map(x=>({category:x,permissions:[]}))
    //data is an array ob object with "category" and "permissions"
    data.forEach(x=>{
      //with each element of data
       x.permissions=this.permissionsOfCategory(x.category)
          //x.permisions is an array of Permision, but 
          //you create an object with "permision", the Permision and "selected"
          .map(p=>({
               permission:p,
               selected:this.havePermission(x.category)
          })
    })
  }
```

And your .html

```
<mat-selection-list>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of data">
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <!--use cat.category-->
        <div mat-subheader>{{ cat.category }}</div>
                <!--use cat.permissions-->
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let permission of cat.permissions"
            <!--use 
            [selected]="permission.selected"
        >
            {{ permission.permission.Name }}
        </mat-list-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-selection-list>
```

I hope don't missing so much (I don't check the code), but remember: the idea is calculate all **one time** -using map to transform an array in an array of objects (one property the array and another property a value calculated) instead use complex function in the .html